# Can keys drop from zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

There are doors that require many keys to open.  Is it possible to get keys as drops or do you have to purchase them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are dropped. The time between drops seemed random and sometimes too long IMO, but i got keys for every gate except for the ones in the 3rd world (still playing...)

Answer (score 3):

From the official [Support page](http://support.popcap.com/pvz2) (click on "Stars, Keys and the Gates they Open!"):

> If you don't have enough Keys to unlock a gate, you can replay levels to earn more. Keys may appear in any level or mini-game, as they are dropped at random by zombies.  Keys also may be among the treasures found in Yeti Zombie Lunchboxes.